# Why does Mathematica simplify $x/x\to1$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

If I enter `x/x`, I get `1`. Such behavior leads to this:

```
Simplify[D[Sqrt[x^2], x, x]]
```

> 0

The same would be even if I use `Together` instead of `Simplify`.

One could then think that $\sqrt{x^2}$ is doubly differentiable at least $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, but if we remove `Simplify` call, we would reveal that it's not:

```
D[Sqrt[x^2], x, x]
```

> -(x^2/(x^2)^(3/2)) + 1/Sqrt[x^2]

Even more ridiculous is this (which I guess is because `x/x` is simplified before feeding to `Assuming`):

```
Assuming[x == 0, x/x]
```

> 1

Why does Mathematica assume $x\ne0$? Is there a way to make it not cancel out such terms?

Comment: Well if you take a look at it, `-(x^2/(x^2)^(3/2)) + 1/Sqrt[x^2]` is exactly zero, except at `x=0`. But From a mathematical standpoint the problem is more like why does mathematicas differential operator `D` not exclude `x=0` in this case.

Comment: Here it's not a problem: `D` gives an expression, which is undefined for $x=0$. It's quite a correct result for function, which isn't differentiable at $x=0$. But then simplifying it to $0$ makes it defined at $x=0$ too, which is incorrect.

Comment: This is *Mathematica*'s default behavior, so it's exactly the expected result. Any undefined symbol is assumed by `Simplify` to be a generic complex number. By generic, I mean not having any isolated special value, such as `0`. You have to use `Assumptions` to  change this default.

Comment: @Jens So how exactly do I use `Assumptions` for this? See update of the question.

Comment: For doing the derivative, I would perhaps approach it as shown in my answer.

Comment: By the way, the issue with `Assuming` in your last example is simply that `$Assumptions` are ignored by the expression `x/x` (specifically `Power`); only  `Simplify` other functions that understand the option `Assumptions` can be affected by `Assuming`. This is also why the assumption of real variables in a second derivative has to be applied once in each differentiation step, which required me to split the second derivative in my answer into two first derivatives wrapped in `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
fun = Sqrt[x^2];

dd = D[fun, x, x];
```

With **V10** we can explicitly define:

```
{dd, FunctionDomain[dd, x]}
```

[image]

Or

```
{Simplify @ dd, FunctionDomain[dd, x]}

{0, x < 0 || x > 0}
```

Also with **V10** you might consider `Inactivate`:

```
di = D[Inactivate@Sqrt[x^2], x, x] // Together
```

[image]

which prevents `Together` from evaluating to `0`

```
di // Activate
```

> 0

Answer (score 10):

Let's define

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x^2]

FullSimplify[D[f[x],x], x ∈ Reals]

(* ==> Sign[x] *)
```

You can use `f'[x]` or `D[f[x],x]` interchangeably here. Then the second derivative is simply

```
FullSimplify[D[Sign[x], x], x ∈ Reals]

(* ==> Derivative[1][Sign][x] *)
```

So doing the second derivative in two steps yields a mathematically correct answer. The derivative of the `Sign` function is not defined, but we can define it in the sense of distributions by replacing `Sign[x]` with `2HeavisideTheta[x]-1`. Then one would obtain this nice result for the second derivative:

```
FullSimplify[D[2 HeavisideTheta[x] - 1, x], 
 x ∈ Reals]

(* ==> 2 DiracDelta[x] *)
```

Here is my initial way to get a mathematically expected result by making the domain explicit over which the function is defined:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x^2], x > 0}, {Undefined, True}}]

Simplify[D[f[x], x, x]]

(* ==> ConditionalExpression[0, x > 0] *)
```

However, this is only a band-aid.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ is also defined for $x\le0$. It's the whole point of it — to be defined for all x (it's $|x|$ in disguise).

Comment: @Ruslan You're right, I'm actually quite surprised after trying this a bit more. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nice catch.  The `Sqrt` bug is not present in my beta V10 (Mac), however.

Comment: My V10 (Win7-64) also returns Sign[x]. Perhaps you should restart.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries You're right, version 10 is working like 8 again - I had an uncleared assumption hanging around.

Answer (score 7):

Here are three approaches to the function:

```
f1[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x^2], x != 0}}, 0]

f2[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x^2], x < 0}, {Sqrt[x^2], x > 0}}, 0]

f3[x_] := Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}, {x, x > 0}}, 0]
```

Their second derivatives.

```
Simplify@D[#[x], x, x] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems that `f2` or `f3` might be used, but `Simplify[f2[x]]` results in `f1[x]`.

```
Simplify[f2[x]] // InputForm
(* Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x^2], x != 0}}, 0] *)
```

So if the functions are simplified, only `f3` gives the correct result:

```
Simplify@D[Simplify@#[x], x, x] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) This is what I was aiming for (before I messed up and wrongly guessed that there was a bug in version 10)...