# Compare algebraic equivalence (regardless of term order) without having to simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I know that in order to find the equivalence of say $ a+b $ and $ b+a $, then:

```
FullSimplify[a + b == b + a]
```

is sufficient. However, suppose I want to compare without simplifying, and simply determine the equivalence of two algebraic statements **regardless** of the ordering of terms? For example, $ a+b = b+a $, but $ \frac{(a+b)^2}{a+b} \neq a+b $.

Edit:

I want Mathematica to tell me commutative equivalence ONLY between two expressions. Consider another example:

$$s_1 = 3 - \sqrt{2}$$
$$s_2 = - \sqrt{2} + 3$$
$$s_3 = 3 - \sqrt{\sqrt{2}}^2$$

I want some function or procedure to tell me that $s_1 = s_2$ but $s_1 \neq s_3$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. `a + b == b + a` evaluates to `True` because `Plus` has `Attribute` `Orderless`.

Comment: In addition to what Henrik said: `(a+b)^2/(a+b)` also automatically evaluates to `a+b`, so it's not really possible to do what you are asking for. One trick to work around it is `Reduce[{x/(a + b) == a + b, x == (a + b)^2}]` or `Reduce[{x/(a + b) == a + b, x == (a + b)^2}, x]`.  `Reduce` will try to generate complete conditions. In this case it will say that this is true only if `a+b != 0`.

Comment: In order to asnwer this question, you have to tell us exactly what yuo mean by "algebraic expression" and your exactt definition of "equivalence".

Comment: I have added further details to (hopefully) better explain my question

Comment: Re your second, the simplification of the LHS is *automatic* -- Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/why-does-mathematica-simplify-x-x-to1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1 = Hold[3 - Sqrt[2]]; s2 = Hold[-Sqrt[2] + 3]; s3 = Hold[3 - Sqrt[Sqrt[2]^2]];
eq[x_, y_] := x === y || x === Reverse[y, 2]; {eq[s1, s2], eq[s1, s3]};
```

returns `{True, False}`. You need the `Hold[]` because `Plus[]` is `Orderless`.

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but it points me in the right direction. Thanks