# How can i specify the indeterminate values in plot

Tags: plotting

Mathematica Plots the function `f[x]=x/x` in [-1,1] with no problem but I need an indicator of singularity in `x=0`. How can I do that?

Comment: `Epilog`? `PlotLabel`? What sort of indicator do you want to have? Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39445/plot-a-piecewise-function-with-black-and-white-disks-marking-discontinuities

Comment: Maybe a white circle indicating that point is indeterminate.

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57489/why-does-mathematica-simplify-x-x-to1 (explains why the automatic `Exclusions` does not work as one might expect).  Compare `Plot[x/(0. + x), {x, -1, 1}, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {None, Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]}]`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this?:

```
Plot[x/x, {x, -1, 1},
 Epilog -> {White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 1}, Offset[{5, 5}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I look for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alp You're welcome. :)