# Remove radicals from denominator

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Memo for the moderator.
Sorry, I am new to "Ask  a question".
Is my writing correct ? Shall I receive a reply  directly to my e-mail address  or somewhere in the StackExchange?

---

My question:
I want to simplify the following expression, when $-1 < x < 1$ and $-1 < y < 1$,

```
sol = Sqrt[1/(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])].
```

By hand I obtain

```
 sol$rat =  Sqrt[(-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/y^2]
```

but, as I have not been able to find a built-in command, I have tried naively, without success after several tests

```
 rational$sol = 
     Sqrt[1/((x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) (-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]))*(-x + Sqrt[
         x^2 + y^2])] // FullSimplify
```

When I search  (e.g., stack exchange ...) "Simplifying Radicals in Numerator and Denominator - Mathematica," I see no satisfying solution.

Comment: `sol /. 1/(z1_ + Sqrt[z2_]) :> (z1 - Sqrt[z2])/(z1^2 - z2)`

Answer (score 11):

You can guide the simplification by providing a `ComplexityFunction`.  It seems that your aim is to make the denominator as simple as possible.  With that in mind, I tried the following

```
Assuming[-1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1, 
  FullSimplify[sol, 
   ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[Denominator[#]] &)]] // Simplify

(* Sqrt[(-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/y^2] *)
```

The `FullSimplify` rewrites the denominator, the `Simplify` tidies the expression a little.

Comment: You and Bob Hanlon have illuminated me

Comment: Unfortunately this result is not exact. sol has no singularity for positive x and y->0, but this result has a (but removable) singularity there. Look at my answer

Comment: This works really nice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
Sqrt[Numerator[sol[[1]]]*(x - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/
   Expand[Denominator[sol[[1]]]*(x - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])]]



  (*  Sqrt[-((x - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/y^2)]   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a high-school algebra approach:

```
$rat = # /. Power[a_ + s_.*Sqrt[b_], -1] :> 
    Power[(a^2 - s^2 b)/(a - s*Sqrt[b]), -1] &;

sol // $rat
(*  Sqrt[-((x - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/y^2)]  *)
```

Other variants:  The `Power[.., -1]` pattern above limits the applicability to a simple factor in the denominator (anywhere in the expression, by the way!).

```
$rat = # /.   (* any factor in denominator *)
    Power[a_ + s_. * Sqrt[b_], p_?Negative] :>
     Power[(a^2 - s^2 b)/(a - s*Sqrt[b]), p] &;

$rat = # /.   (* any sum involving Sqrt[] anywhere in the expression *)
    a_ + s_. * Sqrt[b_] :>
     (a^2 - s^2 b)/(a - s * Sqrt[b]) &;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the results given so far are not exact. `sol`  has no singularity for positive x and y -> 0, but the other results have a (but removable) singularity there.

```
sol1[x_, y_] = Sqrt[1/(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])];

sol2[x_, y_] = Sqrt[(-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/y^2];

{s1 = sol1[1/3, y], s1 /. y -> 0}

(*   {Sqrt[1/(1/3 + Sqrt[1/9 + y^2])], Sqrt[3/2]}   *}

{s2 = sol2[1/3, y], s2 /. y -> 0, Limit[s2, y -> 0]}

(* {Sqrt[(-(1/3) + Sqrt[1/9 + y^2])/y^2], Indeterminate, Sqrt[3/2]} *}
```

The simplification Mathematica did with 'ComplexityFunction' is not exact.

Comment: Instead of "not exact," the docs describe the results as "generically equivalent." In general, *Mathematica* does algebra with generic transformations. Consider [`x/x`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57489), and the docs for `Solve`, `Integrate`, and `FullSimplify` explicitly warn this. From the point of view of algebra, this is fine and accepted in mathematics; from the point of view of functions and their domains, your criticism is valid. Note that the OP's desired solution `sol$rat` is also only generically equivalent.